# zabbix начал сыпать письма

Tags: mysql, администрирование, zabbix, мониторинг

стоит тригер
{Mysql:Uptime.change()}<0
и раньше стоял,
но вчера, забикс, как ненормальный начал сыпать уведомления каждые 2 минуты ,  проблема ! проблема решена..
с серваком БД проблем нет,  нагрузка минимальная,  работает штатно,  в сети все друг друга видят запросы бегают и так далее. Что за беда посетила забикс ?  или все таки бд ?

Comment: Mysql was Restarted on